# Magento Admin buttons don't work

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, cache, localisation

After editing some language files all admin buttons stopped working.

If I try to clear my cache nothing happens when I click at the button related to it.

Does someone know how to fix this?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for JavaScript errors? Most buttons in the admin area are driven by JavaScript `onclick` events written as an attribute directly on the element. And, can you confirm that the entire page is loading (down the copyright info of the page)? Try turning on developer mode in `index.php` to see if you get any exceptions thrown.

Comment: The CSV files shouldnt have that much impact on the functionality. Are the CSV files valid? Did you change anything else? What are you to deploy code to your live server?

Comment: Have you install any new extension. Or you may delete some js files in js folder

Comment: @RickBuczynski following error appears: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: cache_grid_massactionJsObject is not defined'

Comment: @DIONH Search the HTML source of that page for `cache_grid_massactionJsObject` - if its not there, you may have a bad block that doesn't render. Make sure you turn on developer mode in `index.php` as that will tell you right away about rendering errors. Otherwise, maybe `var/log/exception.log` has some details. I would think either an extension is causing this or something custom you did to layout XML.